# Should I normalize this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, normalization

I have a table Items which stores fetched book data from Amazon.  This Amazon data is inserted into Items as users browse the site, so any INSERT that occurs needs to be efficient.

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `Item_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Item_ISBN` char(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Edition` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Authors` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Publisher` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Item_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Item_Data` (`Item_ISBN`,`Title`,`Edition`,`Authors`,`Year`,`Publisher`),
  KEY `ISBN` (`Item_ISBN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Normalizing this table would presumably mean creating tables for Titles, Authors, and Publishers.  My concern with doing this is that the insert would become too complex.. To insert a single Item, I'd have to:

1. Check for the Publisher in Publishers to SELECT Publisher_ID, otherwise insert it and use mysql_insert_id() to get Publisher_ID.
2. Check for the Authors in Authors to SELECT Authors_ID, otherwise insert it and use mysql_insert_id() to get Authors_ID.
3. Check for the Title in Titles to SELECT Title_ID, otherwise insert it and use mysql_insert_id() to get Title_ID.
4. Use those ID's to finally insert the Item (which may in fact be a duplicate, so this whole process would have been a waste..)

Does that argue against normalization for this table?

Note: The goal of Items is *not* to create a comprehensive database of books, so that a user would say "Show me all the books by Publisher X."  The Items table is just used to cache Items for my users' search results.

Comment: Oh, don't forget to put a checkmark down there :]

Comment: i wont, just waiting for all the feedback to come in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering your goal, I definitely *wouldn't* normalize this.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question - don't normalize it!

Answer (score 1):

YES you should normalize it if you don't think it is already. However, as far as I can tell it's already in 5th Normal Form anyway - at least it seems to be based on the "obvious" interpretation of those column names and if you ignore the nullable columns. Why do you doubt it? Not sure why you want to allow nulls for some of those columns though.

> 1.Check for the Publisher in Publishers to SELECT Publisher_ID,
>   otherwise insert it and use
>   mysql_insert_id() to get Publisher_ID

There is no "Publisher_ID" in your table. Normalization has nothing to do with inventing a new "Publisher_ID" attribute. Substituting a "Publisher_ID" in place of Publisher certainly wouldn't make it any more normalized than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where i can see normalization useful in your case is if you want to store information about each author.

However - 
Where normalization could help you - Saving space! Especially if there is a lot of repetition in terms of publishers, authors (that is, if you normalize individual authors table).

So if you are dealing with 10s of millions of rows, normalization will show an impact in terms of space(even performance). If you don't face that situation (which i believe should be the case) you don't need to normalize.

ps - Also think of the future... will there ever be a need? DBs are a long term infrastructure... never design them keeping the now in mind.